# Find exact ASP.NET Type of page from inside a Master page

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, reflection, asp.net-2.0

I'm trying to retrieve a custom Attribute set on a page's class from inside the MasterPage. Normally to do this I would need to reflect directly on the specific class, but inside the Master page it's always referred to as the `Page` type (the parent class).

How do I determine the specific type of the `Page` property?

Here's an example of what I'm *trying* to do:

```
Dim attrs() As Object = Page.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(GetType(MyCustomAttribute), False)
For Each attr As MyCustomAttribute In attrs
    ' Do something '
Next
```

but it only ever returns the attributes attached to the actual `Page` class.

I'd rather not have to derive a new base type from `Page` if I can avoid it.

Here is how my class is defined (in the code-behind):

```
<MyCustom()> _
Partial Class PageClass
```

Am I defining this in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Page` was the actual type, it was a class representing the ASPX page rather than the partial class my attribute was attached to. To find the partial class I only had to do the following:

```
Page.GetType().BaseType
```

and used my attribute-finding code on that.

Thanks to TonyB and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559312/asp-net-gettype-and-fully-qualified-class-names) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the wrong type to GetCustomAttributes

I added a label called "lblMP" to my master page and when I run this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMP.Text = this.Page.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;

        foreach( var a in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(this.Page.GetType()))
        {
            lblMP.Text = String.Format("{0} <br />{1}", lblMP.Text, a);
        }
    }
```

It correctly shows the custom attribute added to Default.aspx.  Here is the output showing my "MPTesting.CustomAttribute" attribute.

```
ASP.default_aspx, App_Web_tkeebnzk, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute
MPTesting.CustomAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DesignerAttribute
System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItemAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DefaultEventAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute
System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializerAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DesignerAttribute
System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializerAttribute
System.ComponentModel.DefaultPropertyAttribute
System.ComponentModel.BindableAttribute
System.Web.UI.ThemeableAttribute
System.Web.UI,Require
```

Comment: My custom attribute does not show up when I do this. Where are you setting the custom attribute? I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the page instance to the master page. I'd probably pass some kind of callback function to the master page from within the page class.